# Python - Library that compute relevance score for text search

Tags: python, mysql, text-search

My idea is to achieve an execution similar to the MySQL MATCH / AGAINST keywords.

Do you know a python library that compute relevance score for text searches?

If not satisfying answers I am going to use a Python connector to MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at PyLucene http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/

```
import os, sys, unittest, lucene
lucene.initVM()

baseDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
sys.path.append(baseDir)

import lia.searching.ScoreTest
from lucene import System

System.setProperty("index.dir", os.path.join(baseDir, 'index'))
unittest.main(lia.searching.ScoreTest)
```

You can found more examples and lia at http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/pylucene/trunk/samples/LuceneInAction/